# Is there a callback in PDFsharp for progress in Document Save?

Tags: progress-bar, c#-3.0, pdfsharp, pdfdocument

Microsoft Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional
Microsoft .Net Framework Version 3.5 SP1
Microsoft Visual C# 2008
PDFsharp 1.32.2608.0

After I generate a PDF document, I save it. The Save takes a while (the document is rather long). Is there a callback in Document.Save that I can use to display a progress bar for the save process?

Comment: How large are you PDF files? How long does it take to save them? Are you referring to `PdfDocument.Save`?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to PdfDocument.Save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

Rendering is somewhat slow and MigraDoc has a callback for progress bars.

But saving usually goes so fast that we didn't see a need for a progress bar yet.

Comment: PDF file is about 7.5 MB. The generation of the PDF document is fast, it's the saving that's slow.

Comment: @Gus 7.5 MB is not really big. We create larger files than that in fractions of a second (using SSDs). So I wonder how many seconds saving takes on your computer and what makes PDFsharp (BTW: which version?) so slow in your scenario.

Comment: When I look at the properties in PDFsharp, I see it was built against .NET Framework 2.0. Should I recompile under 3.5?

Comment: @Gus .NET Framework 3.5 uses the same CLR 2.0 that .NET Framework 2.0 also uses. Do not expect significant changes. It would be good to have code we can run in a profiler. http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/IssueSubmissions.ashx